# How to scale EC2 instance using terraform without deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to terraform, I am trying to scale my ec2 instance vertically, when I use `terraform apply` It always delete the instance first and then recreate it. Is there any way I can get the scaled-up instance without deleting.

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code and the output of the plan that wants to destroy the instance? Also what version of Terraform and the AWS provider are you using?

Comment: If you are changing the instance type, terraform will destroy and recreate the instance. Also, if you are using userdata, on centos on redhat terraform has had problems and always destroys the instance. You would have to ignore changes to it.

Comment: @victorm not true, using the `lifecycle` block you can `ignore_changes = ["user_data", "instance_type"]` and avoid destructions.

Comment: @ehime that is what I'm saying

Comment: @victorm that isn't true at all. Terraform has been able to handle scaling up the instance size by stopping the instance, changing the size and then starting it again for a long time now. The exception would be when moving between instance classes (not allowed by the AWS API so Terraform uses ForceNew in this case) or on a super old version of Terraform.

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes) property in the lifecycle.

you can try something like this:

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags, e.g. because of a management agent
      # updates these based on some ruleset managed elsewhere.
      tags,
      # this is for your use case.
      instance_type
    ]
  }
}
```